Problem with dtplyr - `by` can't contain join column `V2`, `explicit` which is missing from RHS
I am using dtplyr for speeding operation on a large tibble and I am encountering a problem that I can't figure out. The following is a minimal example.
d <- tibble(
  rownnum = c(1L, 2L),
  stationID = c(1L, 2L),
  groupMemberID = c(0L, 0L),
  workCategory = factor(c("I", "A")),
  stationName = c("RW", "RW"),
  timeSpent = c(period(14060), period(3600)),
  time_grouping = c(as.POSIXct("2023-01-03 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2023-01-03 00:00:00")),
  time_grouping_label = c("2023-01-03", "2023-01-03")
)

d
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  rownnum stationID groupMemberID workCategory stationName timeSpent time_grouping              time_grouping_label
    <int>     <int>         <int> <fct>        <chr>       <Period>  <dttm>                     <chr>              
1       1         1             0 I            RW          14060S    2023-01-03 00:00:00.000000 2023-01-03         
2       2         2             0 A            RW          3600S     2023-01-03 00:00:00.000000 2023-01-03   


d <- d |>
  lazy_dt() |> 
  group_by(stationID, stationName,
           time_grouping, time_grouping_label,
           workCategory) |>
  summarize(cat_time = sum(timeSpent), cat_count = n(),
            .groups = "drop_last") |>
  mutate(tot_time = sum(cat_time), pct = 100 * cat_time/tot_time,
         tot_count = sum(cat_count)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(cat_time_period = seconds_to_period(cat_time),
         tot_time_period = seconds_to_period(tot_time)) |>
  complete(workCategory, nesting(stationID, stationName,
                                 time_grouping, time_grouping_label),
           fill = list(cat_time = 0, cat_count = 0, tot_time = 0, pct = 0,
                       tot_count = 0, cat_time_period = period(0),
                       tot_time_period = period(0)),
           explicit = FALSE) |>
  relocate(workCategory, .after = time_grouping_label) |>
  arrange(stationID, time_grouping, workCategory) |> 
  as_tibble()

Error in `common_by.list()` at dplyr/R/join-common-by.R:10:3:
! `by` can't contain join column `V2`, `explicit` which is missing from RHS.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong and how to fix?
I have tried various things like removing the fill spec from complete, replacing with expand etc, to no avail. Appreciate any help.

Sorry, didn't mention explicitly, but the code runs fine with just dplyr, problem only arises when using dtplyr.

The error is actually occurring from the pct in the mutate.  The grouping isn't working well.  Not sure why though.

Not sure exactly why, but error resolves for me if I change cat_time = sum(timeSpent) to cat_time = sum(timeSpent) |> as.numeric() (making it a normal dbl instead of a time period), and add as_tibble() |> before the complete() step.

Hmmm....changing cat_time to numeric and shifting as_tibble() above complete doesn't seem to work for me. Now, a different error:
Error in [.data.table(_DT114[, .(cat_time = sum(timeSpent), cat_count = .N),  :    Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 1 in column 'pct'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Argh! I was stupid, I edit the wrong place. As the error message said, sum(timeSpent) was still the same.
It does work exactly as Jon said, with an as.numeric() pipe after sum(timeSpent) and as_tibble() above complete....
